# How to disable the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security 4

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm migrating a JSF application from Spring Security 3.2 to 4.0.1. This version changes many default urls, for example the default login url to `/login`.

The application has its own login page (using JSF AJAX) and it is still displayed when calling `/login`, but all POST-Requests to this URL (and so all AJAX-Requests from the Login-Page) are captured by the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and that is trying to process the authentication, causing the request to get redirected to the loginform again.

After looking at the code this url seems to be hard-coded:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}
```

So I have to disable this filter completely, or better, avoid it's creation. Can anybody point me how I can do it.

Changing my login page to another url is working, but is not the nice solution.

EDIT: I have created a Bugticket in Spring Security for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2992

EDIT 2: I've found another workaround: If I set the login-processing-url for the form-login to something unused it is working, but seems to be very hacky. There should be a way to disable it completely. Also it should be stated in the migration guide, I lost hours until I found this.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context or code examples?  Have you looked into what is calling this function that you want to disable?

Comment: Which Spring Security version are you trying to upgrade to - 4.0.0 or 4.0.1?

Comment: I've edited the question to show that I'm upgrading to 4.0.1. I have done nothing special in the code, what exactly do you want to see?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that you are trying to upgrade to Spring Security 4.0.0 (the latest available version is 4.0.1).

Spring Security 3.x used `spring_security_login` as the default login URL (`source`: [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login-attributes)).  This could be set to a custom value as `<security:form-login login-page="/login">` and mapped to a controller to render a custom page.

Spring Security 4.x has abandoned `spring_security_login` and switched to `login` as the default login URL (`source`: [official Spring Security 4.x migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login)).  Therefore, the URL `login` now goes to the default Spring Security infrastructure, that displays the default, auto-generated login page.

There [was a bug in 4.0.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2919) due to which the default infrastructure was still getting used in cases where the URL `/login` was manually mapped to a custom controller method.  This bug has been fixed in 4.0.1. Do try upgrading to Spring Security 4.0.1 to see if you can use `/login` as the login URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already found that bug. But I'm upgrading to 4.0.1... My custom Login-Page is already shown, it's just that all POST-Requests to this URL were interrupted by the filter.

Comment: I had tried a sample with Spring Security 4.0.1 but did not face any problem of the sort you have described.  Since you are facing a problem with POST, better raise another bug with the Spring Security team for them to investigate and fix for the next planned release because the described behaviour is certainly unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could call `setFilterProcessesUrl(String)` (or, equivalently, `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`) to override the default of `/login`.